# how to lock&unlock a mutex using windows.h

Tags: c++, winapi

OK so I am trying to learn the basics of multi threading and in this case am trying to use a mutex to control access to the shared buffer. I introduced all the delays and while loop to magnify the problem which is the mutex seems to not be locked nor is my second thread actually waiting for the mutex object to be unlocked. I followed the msdn syntax best I could if someone can point out the mistakes I am making that would be very much appreciated. below is code and then the output. in case the pic isn't viewable it prints the data as 1 1 1 1 several iterations before finally printing the correct values which shows it is not waiting for the mutex at all.

```
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>

struct data{
        uint8_t accel;
        uint8_t check;
        uint8_t testint;
        uint8_t value;
};

char buff[1000];
bool writef = false;
HANDLE mymutex;


void thread1() {
    
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    OpenMutexW(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, TEXT("firstmutex"));
    if (mymutex == NULL) printf("mutex failed here: %d \n", GetLastError());

    std::cout << "started thread id = " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    //create instance of data and assign the actual data    
    data data1;
    data* ptdata = &data1; //crteate a pointer to the struct object
    printf("pointers 2 data1 \t %p \n ", ptdata);//DEBUG 
    data1.accel = 45;
    data1.check = 34;
    data1.testint = 2;
    data1.value = 19;
    printf("pointer 2 the buffer \t %p \n", buff);//DEBUG AID

    //lock the buff for thread 1 access
    memcpy(buff, ptdata, 4); //copy the content fo data1 into the buffer 
    writef = true;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 50000000; i++){} //delay
    ReleaseMutex(mymutex);

}


void thread2() {
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    bool read = false;
    std::cout << "started thread id = " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    data data2;
    data* dataout = &data2;
    memset(dataout, 0, sizeof(data2));
    printf("p 2 dataout \t %p \n ", dataout);
    while (!read) {
        int c = 0;
        //we need to lock the buff while performing this operation
        printf("waiting %d : \n", c);
        WaitForSingleObject(mymutex, INFINITE); // says wait for the mutext to be released indefinantly
        memcpy(dataout, buff, sizeof(buff + 1)); // copy the data in the buffer to data2 structure.

        printf("this should be the data from the source : ");
        printf(" %d \t %d \t %d \t %d \n", dataout->accel, dataout->check, dataout->testint, dataout->value); //print out the original data
        ReleaseMutex(mymutex); // releases the mutex after a full copy and print occurs 
        c++;
        if (dataout->accel > 1) read = true;
    } 
}

int main() {

    std::cout << sizeof(int);
    std::cout << sizeof(char) << std::endl;

    mymutex = CreateMutexW(NULL, FALSE, TEXT("firstmutex")); // parameters 1= security level 2= ownership 3= object name
    if (mymutex == NULL)printf("mutex creation failed: %d \n", GetLastError());

    memset(buff, 1, sizeof(buff)); //zero out the buffer to initialize and reset

    std::thread datasource(thread1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++); // this is just a delay 
    std::thread dataoutput(thread2);
    datasource.join();
    dataoutput.join();
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;

}
```

[image]

Comment: Look at this document. (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/#:~:text=std%3A%3Amutex&text=mutex%20objects%20provide%20exclusive%20ownership,be%20a%20standard%2Dlayout%20class).

Comment: Look up [std::lock_guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard).

Comment: Totally unrelated: Don't mix the `...W` functions with the `TEXT` macro. `TEXT` is intended to allow you to use the functions without the W and let the build options used select ANSI or Unicode. That said, this is 2020 and the macro-mess that is `TEXT` and the wrapper around the `W` and `A` functions was intended to solve a problem in the late 1990s when Microsoft had two lines of OSes and wanted code to compile for both. This was rendered obsolete in the early 2000s when Windows XP wiped out all of its predecessors. These days just use the `W` functions and Unicode end-to-end.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-mutex-objects

Comment: If `mymutex = CreateMutexW(NULL, FALSE, TEXT("firstmutex"));` is changed to `mymutex = CreateMutexW(NULL, FALSE, L"firstmutex");` it will always work unless you need to compile to a very old OS.

Comment: [Developers Who Use Spaces Make More Money Than Those Who Use Tabs](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/15/developers-use-spaces-make-money-use-tabs/).

Comment: @chung huang I like the std implementation as it would be better for cross platform code, but I looked closer at my code and developed another question. I wanted the buffer to be global in order for the threads to recognize it but doing so I have not enclosed the actual memory of the char buff in a mutex just code in my threads that execute stuff onto that memory location does this render the mutex useless on that section of memory?

Comment: @user4581301 good to know thanks!

Comment: for what you use name for mutex ? for what you call `OpenMutexW` ? the thread#1 never acquire mutex but call `Release`, and main - are your sure that mutex is what you need for your task ? (unclear your task at all)

Comment: A mutex isn't tied to any particular range of memory. The sole purpose of a mutex is that it can be owned by at most 1 thread at any given time.

Comment: @llnspectable hmm ok well that is were I am confused I guess because I get that it is so one thread at a time will have access to a shared resources but in my mind I was trying to make the buffer a shared and lockable resources for the threads would not be altering that memory location at the same time. so refining my question then, how do you lock access to the buffer using a mutex? how do you ensure the mutexes scope includes certain global variables I should say?

Comment: @MacLCM - mutex have not any *scope*

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is the above code modified to simply test and learn one way to use mutex to control a threads' use of data. Also I like sticking to the standard library as much as possible for cross platform functionality and the lack of dependency on special header files. So I'm glad comments posted earlier steered me in that direction. Anyways this code creates a mutex and protects a buffer as the second thread tries to read and output the buffer before the first thread can  copythe data to the buffer. the mutex successfully prevents this and thread 2 only outputs the buffer once it gains control of the mutex.

````
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mutex>


struct data{
        uint8_t accel;
        uint8_t check;
        uint8_t testint;
        uint8_t value;
};

char buff[500];
bool writef = false;
std::mutex buff_mutex; //create the mutex around the buffer

void thread1() {
    
    buff_mutex.lock();// lock the buffer variable
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

    std::cout << "started thread id = " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    //create instance of data and assign the actual data    
    data data1;
    data* ptdata = &data1; //crteate a pointer to the struct object
    printf("pointers 2 data1 \t %p \n ", ptdata);//DEBUG 
    data1.accel = 45;
    data1.check = 34;
    data1.testint = 2;
    data1.value = 19;
    printf("pointer 2 the buffer \t %p \n",buff);//DEBUG AID

    //lock the buff for thread 1 access
    memcpy(buff, ptdata, 4); //copy the content fo data1 into the buffer 
    writef = true;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 50000000; i++){} //delay
    buff_mutex.unlock(); // unlock the buffer for the second thread to acces it after the write op has been completed
    

}


void thread2() {
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    bool read = false;
    std::cout << "started thread id = " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    data data2;
    data* dataout = &data2;
    memset(dataout, 0, sizeof(data2));
    printf("p 2 dataout \t %p \n ", dataout);
    while (!read) {
        int c = 0;
        //we need to lock the buff while performing this operation
        if (buff_mutex.try_lock()) { //try to unlock the mutex the return value is a bool true= success false= could not lock the mutex
            memcpy(dataout, buff, sizeof(buff + 1)); // copy the data in the buffer to data2 structure.
            printf("this should be the data from the source : ");
            printf(" %d \t %d \t %d \t %d \n", dataout->accel, dataout->check, dataout->testint, dataout->value); //print out the original data 
            read = true;
            buff_mutex.unlock();
        }
        else {
            printf("failed attempt %d \n", c);
            c++;
        }
        
    } 
}

int main() {

    std::cout << sizeof(int);
    std::cout << sizeof(char) << std::endl;

    memset(buff, 1, sizeof(buff)); //zero out the buffer to initialize and reset

    std::thread datasource(thread1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++); // this is just a delay 
    std::thread dataoutput(thread2);
    datasource.join();
    dataoutput.join();
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;

} ```
````

Comment: and windows.h nor fstream is actually necessary here they are just left over includes from previous exercises

Comment: I think you can put `int c = 0` outside the loop because it will be initialized to 0 every time the loop is looped.

Comment: @Zhu Song that is true, I created c thought just to show if it did loop but that was simply a way to test if the mutex was actually blocking since if it was working correctly it should never loop which it doesn't with the new code it iterates once and gets blocked until the mutex returns true and then procedes and sets the reads bool (the while loop condition) to true in the process so it exits after first go around

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.